# SQL Server: Is it possible to synchronize user GUIDs between two databases if the users are not tied to a login?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-administration

Our project uses SQL Server database users without logins to implement security and row-level filtering.

We have implemented a very basic form of mirroring in which the transactional database is backed up and restored nightly to a second “mirror” copy. A web service pulls data from the mirror.

However, we need to log web service requests in the transactional database so that they are not wiped out when the next mirror is restored.

We attempted to implement this by replacing the log tables in the mirror with synonyms pointing at the "real" tables in the transactional database.

However, attempts to write to the synonyms invariably fail with error messages such as:

> The server principal "" is not able to access the database "" under the current security context

I’m guessing this happens because, during restore, the users are re-created and assigned new GUIDs?

I've found lots of answers that talk about re-connecting a database user to a SQL Server login using `sp_change_users_login` or `ALTER USER`, but these solutions don't seem applicable, since these database users don't have logins.

Is there some way to ensure that users in the mirrored database are recognized as the same user in the transactional database if their usernames are the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, when you `CREATE` a `USER` (or `LOGIN`) you can define the `SID` when you create it:

```
USE DB1;
GO
CREATE USER SampleUser WITHOUT LOGIN WITH SID = 0x010500000000000903000000F759D99F7F71EC459908C0A30B39056C;

USE DB2;
GO
CREATE USER SampleUser WITHOUT LOGIN WITH SID = 0x010500000000000903000000F759D99F7F71EC459908C0A30B39056C;
```

Comment: Very helpful! I can think now of two solutions:

1) Drop and re-create the users in all our (many) databases, assigning the SID using a hashing function such as HASHBYTES('MD5',@Username), ensuring that the users are functionally the same everywhere.

2) Drop and re-create the users in the mirror database, assigning the SID from the transactional database.

Approach 2 seems safer, but Approach 1 seems really flexible.

Is there anything fundamentally bad about approach 1?

Comment: The only problem, either way, is that when you `DROP` the user you'll need to ensure that you add any permissions after you recreate it, @JimBurnell .

Comment: That's not a problem. User creation, permissions, and assignment to roles are scripted in a stored procedure based on values in the database.

Comment: can this even work? wouldnt it be a major security issue? A db owner of databaseX would create a user with sid 123 and get access to databaseY, because there is a sid 123 user there? am i missing something? In the documentation: "The WITHOUT LOGIN clause creates a user that is not mapped to a SQL Server login. It can connect to other databases as guest." 
If guest is enabled for the transactional db [ use transactionaldb; grant connect to guest;] then the error [The server principal.. not able to access the database..] will go away,but the loginless user has a different context, i.e guest

Comment: In that event, it would only be a security concern if the `guest` user had privileges it shouldn't, @lptr . Normally `guest` would have no inherent permissions, so someone enabling it to have access *should* more than understand what they are doing. Also, I use `WITHOUT LOGIN` above, however, the OP could be talking about contained databases as well. An SID can be specified with the creation of a `USER`, however, the `USER` must with be created with `WITHOUT LOGIN` or be provided a password and be inside a contained database.

Comment: in both cases, for WITHOUT LOGIN and WITH PASSWORD, the sid is meaningless. Two users in two separate online databases can NOT be identified as the same user even if they have the same sid.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some way to ensure that users in the mirrored database are
>   recognized as the same user in the transactional database if their
>   usernames are the same?

The answer is:No

Users without logins are database principals **only**. For any users, in different dbs, to be "one" they need to "point" to the same server principal: login. It is the login that "connects" database users.

> I’m guessing this happens because, during restore, the users are
>   re-created and assigned new GUIDs?

The SIDs (Security IDentifiers) of the database users do not change when the db is restored. 
The fact that the sids do not change but remain the same, requires the actions you have found (sp_change_users_login or ALTER USER) when a database is restored to another server.

3 options for cross database actions:

1. cross database ownership chaining
2. impersonation
3. module signing

I cannot tell if crossdb chaining will work, since the loginless users do not have any security essence when they leave their database. Outside their database, loginless users have no security attributes, they lose their "identity".

On the other hand, impersonation and module signing can work, because the security attributes are warranted by another principal.

Following is a "simplistic" poc, for db users without login, performing cross db actions with sql-modules signed by an asymmetric key. There are plenty of examples online for module signing with certificates and the workings are the same. Most articles you'll find online, execute the signed modules in the scope of a server principal (exec as login, exec signed_module) while the loginless users have no server level existence. 
Signed modules need to be executed by a trusted entity for the signature to take effect(a login is by definition trusted) and for loginless users their trustiness comes from their own db. For that, the db where the loginless users reside must be TRUSTWORTHY ON.

In the poc, there is a signed multiline table valued function in the mirrordb which is used for selecting data from the transactional db. The function is the base for a view (views cannot be signed). The view is the target of DML. The actual dml action(s) are performed by signed INSTEAD OF triggers.

You need to generate&adjust the path to the asymmetric key before executing the script.

Impersonation could work the same way(take away the signing related actions and create each module with EXECUTE AS)

```
create database transactionaldb
go

create database mirrordb
go

--target table in transactionaldb
use transactionaldb
go

create table targettable
(
id int identity,
username nvarchar(128) default(user_name()),
somevalue varchar(10),
thedate datetime default(getdate())
)
go

--mirror db, userwithout login
use mirrordb
go

create user userwithoutlogin without login
go

--synonym, just for testing
create synonym targettablesynonym for transactionaldb..targettable
go
--for testing, grant permissions on synonym to loginless user
grant select, insert, update, delete on targettablesynonym to userwithoutlogin
go


--switch to loginless user and select from synonym
execute as user = 'userwithoutlogin'
go

select * from targettablesynonym --The server principal "S-1-2-3-4..." is not able to access the database "transactionaldb" under the current security context.
go
--revert
revert
go


/*
1) cross db ownership chaining 
2) impersonation
3) module signing (below)
*/

--module signing, asymmetric key
--create a strong key/name file using sn.exe  :  sn -k 2048 c:\testdata\asymkeytest.snk //use key size 2048 for sql2016 on.


--the same for transactionaldb
use transactionaldb
go

--master key transactionaldb
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'M@st3rkeyTransactional'
GO

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY asymkeytest  
    AUTHORIZATION dbo  
    FROM FILE = 'c:\testdata\asymkeytest.snk';  
GO

create user asymkeytransactionaldbuser from asymmetric key asymkeytest
go

--grant permissions on targettable to asymkeytransactionaldbuser
grant select, insert, update, delete on targettable to asymkeytransactionaldbuser;
go


use mirrordb
go

--master key mirrordb
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'M@st3rkeyMirror'
GO

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY asymkeytest  
    AUTHORIZATION dbo  
    FROM FILE = 'c:\testdata\asymkeytest.snk';  
GO

--a db user from the asymkey? not really needed
--create user asymkeymirrordbuser from asymmetric key asymkeytest
go


select is_master_key_encrypted_by_server, *
from sys.databases
where name in ('transactionaldb', 'mirrordb');
go


use mirrordb
go

--a function in mirror which reads the table from transactional
create or alter function dbo.fnreadtargettablefromtransactionaldb()
returns @result table
(
    id int,
    username nvarchar(128),
    somevalue varchar(10),
    thedate datetime
)
as
begin

    insert into @result(id, username, somevalue, thedate)
    select id, username, somevalue, thedate
    from transactionaldb.dbo.targettable;

    return;
end
go

--grant select on loginless user
grant select on fnreadtargettablefromtransactionaldb to userwithoutlogin;
go


--switch to loginless user and select from function
execute as user = 'userwithoutlogin'
go

select * from fnreadtargettablefromtransactionaldb(); --The server principal "S-1-2-3-4..." is not able to access the database "transactionaldb" under the current security context.
go
--revert
revert
go

--sign the function with the asymmetric key
add signature to fnreadtargettablefromtransactionaldb by ASYMMETRIC KEY asymkeytest;

--... after signing
execute as user = 'userwithoutlogin'
go

select * from fnreadtargettablefromtransactionaldb(); --The server principal "S-1-2-3-4..." is not able to access the database "transactionaldb" under the current security context.
go
--revert
revert
go

--the signed module/function is accessing the transactionaldb but it is NOT trusted
--it could be trusted if:
--   a. it was called in the context of a server principal (login, by definition it is trusted)
--   b. if the source db of the signed module is trustful

--make the source db of the signed module trustful
alter database mirrordb set trustworthy on;

--test again
execute as user = 'userwithoutlogin'
go

--synonym (needs permissions now, at the destination)
select * from targettablesynonym

--signed function, working, permissions from the asymmetric key
select * from fnreadtargettablefromtransactionaldb(); --works
go
--revert
revert
go


use mirrordb
go
--complete interface
create or alter view transactiontableview
as
select *
from fnreadtargettablefromtransactionaldb()
go

--view permissions
grant select, insert, update, delete on transactiontableview to userwithoutlogin;
go


--instead of insert trigger
create or alter trigger insteadofinsertonview on transactiontableview instead of insert
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    if not exists(select * from inserted)
    begin
        return;
    end

    insert into transactionaldb.dbo.targettable(username, somevalue, thedate)
    select user_name(), somevalue, thedate
    from inserted;
end
go
--sign
add signature to insteadofinsertonview by ASYMMETRIC KEY asymkeytest;
go


execute as user = 'userwithoutlogin'
go

    insert into transactiontableview(somevalue)
    select col
    from (values('one'), ('2'), ('3')) as t(col);

    select * from transactiontableview

go
--revert
revert
go


/***********************************************/

--check the security token of a signed module when db trustworthy is off
alter database mirrordb set trustworthy off;
go

--create a proc
create or alter procedure showsecuritytokens
as
begin

    select 'mirror_db' as dbname, *
    from mirrordb.sys.user_token
    union all
    select 'transactional_db' as dbname, *
    from transactionaldb.sys.user_token;
end
go

--sign the proc for accessing transactionaldb info
add signature to showsecuritytokens by ASYMMETRIC KEY asymkeytest;
go

--permissions
grant execute on showsecuritytokens to userwithoutlogin
go

--enable guest for transactionaldb
use transactionaldb
go

grant connect to guest
go


use mirrordb
go
--switch to loginless user
execute as user = 'userwithoutlogin'
go

exec showsecuritytokens
--when from an untrusted source: the signed module does not get the GRANTs of the asymmetric key (at the destination) 
/*
thedb_______________principal_id__name_________________________type___________________________usage
transactional_db____5_____________asymkeytransactionaldbuser___USER MAPPED TO ASYMMETRIC KEY__DENY ONLY    
*/
go
--revert
revert
go



--cleanup
/*
use master
go
drop database transactionaldb
go
drop database mirrordb
go
*/
```